# JQuery UI: is it possible to know where an object has been dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

what I want to do is to know where (not in terms of position (x, y), but a reference to the DOM element) an object was dropped.

I have a grid made up with divs where you can drop various items and I need to know which div on the grid was the item dropped on (getting its id would be fine). The callback function

```
function(event, ui) { //code here }
```

has just that ui object who doesn't apparently contain any information about this, but only about the draggable item or its helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use is the jQuery `Droppable` class, which you can read about in the [jQuery docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/).

Basically, for every element that you wish to be able to drop a draggable element on, you create a `Droppable` object, which will trigger once another object is dragged onto it. This is the example from the jQuery docs:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                    .find( "p" )
                        .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        });
    });
```

The `$(this)` in that example is the element you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I don't really know how I've missed this :)